# Java Web Start Application reading local files

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

For a school project, I need to create an application that searches for the csv file with the correct file name on the user's computer and show the data on the application. From my understanding, the javax.jnlp.OpenFileService requires the user to choose which file to send to the application; is there a way to enable the application to search for the file actively in a specific folder? or Can the application create a folder on the user's drive when it launches and seek for files from that folder?

For example, one of the application's function would be to analyze a stock's price behavior. To achieve this goal, the user needs to download the historical price of that stock from yahoo finance as a csv file. When the user types in the stock sticker which is also the name of the csv file in the application, it will display the analysis regarding to that stock.

I'm very new to this topic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean "search for the correct csv"? Do you know the the files name? Do you know the files location? Or your application needs to search on the whole file system to find a specific file? Please more details.

Comment: I meant correct csv file name. Sorry for the confusion and thank you for your comments.

Comment: Sorry but still not clear. Please try to maybe give an example of the input and output your programs expects.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. I have provided an example of such usage.

Comment: You don't need to create a folder. All you need to do is put the CSV file in a folder you expect it to be at and then just follow the steps as in this tutorial: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

Comment: Hi George, welcome to Stackoverflow. First I want to challenge your decision to use web start. So why do you use webstart? Webstart has been deprecated and will be removed in future. All the things you asked are possible with a normal java application. You can call web services or download files( csv), create folders and search for files...

Comment: Hi Lonzak, thank you for your comment. The problem is distribution. If I don't use Webstart, I have to put the app on my website with a download link and user needs to download it. That leads to potential outdated JRE and Operating Environment issues on the user end. I'm very new to this, if you have any advice on distribution, please do share. The code is written in JavaFx. Thank you.

Comment: You use the distribution mechanism provided by javaFX: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm This is way easier since you bundle the jre with your application etc.